# How can I access python shell in sublime text 3?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Is it possible to set up sublime text for full stack python development. By this, I mean the following:
 1. python shell where I can input an expression and instantly get the result,
 2. the shell will work for the 'input' method, which will prompt the user to enter data.

I have installed the theme and color scheme, but the console/shell is not working or I did not get the correct package from the package control. I want an environment where I can work in the sublime text without shifting into the IDLE. Please help me kindly if you know how to do it.

Comment: There is a SublimeREPL package that sounds like what you want, but I would strongly recommend PyCharm instead

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

As @cricket_007 states you can install SublimeREPL and run the current file via `Tools >>> SublimeREPL >>> Python >>> Python - Run current file`. This interprets the python file in a Sublime Text view and inputs are possible. However since this is not a build system you can create a build system from this (click `Tools >>> Build System >>> New Build System...` and paste):

```js
{
    "target": "repl_open",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
    "type": "subprocess",
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "cwd": "$file_path",
    "external_id": "python",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

As an alternative one could run the file in a terminal, by using the following build system. This will create a new terminal and execute the file in python and afterwards await pressing enter.

```js
{
    "selector": "source.python",
    "windows": {
        "shell_cmd": "start \"$file_name\" cmd /c \"python $file_name & pause\""
    },
    "linux": {
        "shell_cmd": "xterm -T \"$file_name\" -e bash -c \"python $file_name; echo Press enter to exit... & read\""
    }
}
```

*Feel free to add the osx option*